# Checked() function on a multidimensional array

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, options, save-post

I am generating checkboxes dynamically on one of the option pages. This the code that I'm using to create multiple checkboxes:

```
<?php foreach($shopCategories as $shopCategory) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $shopCategory->term_id; ?>" 
       name="term_meta[ss_aff_categories][]"
       <?php checked($term_meta['ss_aff_categories'], $shopCategory->term_id, true) ?>>
           <?php echo $shopCategory->name; ?><br/>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that with the`checked()` function in place I receive a notice:

> Notice: Array to string conversion ... in
>   wp-includes/general-template.php on line 3099

The function does not check the selected fields.

I think that it cannot handle multiple arrays (`name="term_meta[ss_aff_categories][]"`) in this setup.

How can I apply the `checked()` function to check values in a multidimensional array - similar to the one above?

Answer (score 3):

The question is from a long time ago but, just for reference, in this particular case and if somebody simply wants to use the `checked` function with what seems to be an `array` (instead of doing the test and output 'checked` on the spot) here is a drop-in solution:

```
checked( in_array( $shopCategory->term_id, $term_meta['ss_aff_categories'] ) )
```

This works because `checked` can take only one argument and compare the value of it with the default second argument which is set to `boolean` `true`. So in this case, if the `$shopCategory->term_id` value is in the `$term_meta['ss_aff_categories']` array the `in_array` function will return boolean `true`. Ultimately, the value that we pass  to `checked`, along with the default second argument of `checked`, are converted to strings and compared.